# Django channels Group send stop working

Tags: django, websocket, django-views, django-channels

I am working on ordering system and using django-channels for sending a notification to an admin about the order has been placed and it works only with 1-2 orders perfectly after that no notification.

## consumers.py

```
from channels import Group
from channels.sessions import channel_session   


@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    print "Connect"
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    Group('admin-channel', channel_layer=message.channel_layer).add(message.reply_channel)  


@channel_session
def ws_disconnect(message):
    print "Disconnect"
    Group('admin-channel', channel_layer=message.channel_layer).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

## views.py

```
def view(request):
    # some order realted processing
    message = {
        "status": "Success",
        "order-id": order.id
    }

    Group('admin-channel').send({
        "text": json.dumps(message)
    })
```

## chat.js

```
$(function () {
    // When we're using HTTPS, use WSS too.
    var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
    var chatsock = new ReconnectingWebSocket(ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + "/order");  

    chatsock.onmessage = function (message) {
        var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
        console.log(data);
    };
});
```

## settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
        "ROUTING": "cashier.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be more logical and easy to send a `Django signal` while rendering the form for the order? like if form is valid -> send signal. End of the story no sockets or other thing necessary.

Comment: no, i have to give real time notification to the admin.

Comment: Please update your question with your Django version and your `CHANNEL_LAYERS` settings.

Comment: @RajaSimon i am using django==1.9

Comment: Did you received any error message in your chrome console ?